# HERE maps - Move map position

Tags: here-api

I would like to do very simple thing which is moving HERE map left / right / up / down. Let's focus on one thing, so moving map up. This works fine when dragging the map but how to do that from code?

I've tried taking current `GeoBox` modifying latitude only (keeping longitude unchanged) and then using:

```
camera.lookAt(myNewBox, new GeoOrientationUpdate(null, (double) 0));
```

It worked but I guess that due to spherical coordinate system map not only moved up but also to the right (of course it depends on location). Anyway, I would only like to move the map in one direction, preferably by just giving it value in px / dp. Is it possible? Or can I maybe simulate drag from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve what I needed. Initial approach with moving whole box:

```
camera.lookAt(myNewBox, new GeoOrientationUpdate(null, (double) 0));
```

resulted in map zooming out a bit (due to spherical coordinate system) because map wanted to show new corners and since earth is not flat it had to zoom out it my case. Probably in case of different coordinates it could be zooming in as well.

In order to achieve this without zoom effect I've used different variant of `lookAt` function which shows single point only:

```
camera.lookAt(new GeoCoordinates(centerPointLatitude + shift, centerPointLongitude));
```

It required computing center point first but it does the job without any zoom or left / right shift.

Answer (score 0):

to programmatically move the map in a specific direction (e.g., up) without affecting the longitude, you can achieve this by updating the `GeoBox` of the map. Below is a solution in Android using the HERE Mobile SDK:

```java
import com.here.sdk.core.GeoBox;
import com.here.sdk.core.GeoCoordinates;
import com.here.sdk.core.GeoOrientationUpdate;
import com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.Camera;
import com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapViewLite;

public class MapMovementHelper {

    private final MapViewLite mapView;

    public MapMovementHelper(MapViewLite mapView) {
        this.mapView = mapView;
    }

    public void moveMapUp(double distanceInMeters) {
        Camera camera = mapView.getCamera();

        // Get the current visible region (GeoBox) of the map.
        GeoBox currentGeoBox = mapView.getBoundingBox();

        // Calculate the new latitude for moving the map up.
        double newLatitude = currentGeoBox.getTopLeft().latitude + distanceInMeters / mapView.getPixelScaleAt(0);

        // Create a new GeoBox with the updated latitude.
        GeoBox newGeoBox = new GeoBox(
                new GeoCoordinates(newLatitude, currentGeoBox.getTopLeft().longitude),
                currentGeoBox.getBottomRight());

        // Move the camera to the new GeoBox.
        camera.lookAt(newGeoBox, new GeoOrientationUpdate(null, (double) 0));
    }
}
```

This code defines a `MapMovementHelper` class that provides a method `moveMapUp(double distanceInMeters)` to move the map up by a specified distance in meters. The method calculates the new latitude based on the current visible region and updates the `GeoBox` accordingly.

You can use this helper class in your activity or fragment:

```java
MapMovementHelper mapMovementHelper = new MapMovementHelper(mapView);
mapMovementHelper.moveMapUp(1000); // Move the map up by 1000 meters.
```

Adjust the `distanceInMeters` parameter as needed for your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your code looks very similar to what I already have. There are some differences e.g. I don't have function like `geoBox.getTopLeft()`, instead I have property `geoBox.northEastCorner`. In my case `GeoBox` takes bottom right corner first and the other one second, while in your case it's the other way around. The main difference is that I've updated latitude in both corners while you're updating it in one corner only. Anyway, I've tried your approach and still behavior is the same, map moves up and also to the right.

Comment: I've just noticed that map doesn't move right. It actually slightly modifies zoom level (probably to take both corners into consideration) and just in my case the impression is that it moves right. Anyway, what I would like to achieve is moving the map in straight line and probably spherical coordinate system would have to be considered somehow to achieve that.